# PostGIS SQL query to find a polygon that intersects with a line

Tags: postgis, sql, postgis-2.0

I need to build a PostGIS query that would select every polygon inside an area the river is flowing through.

I'd better describe with an example below: There is a river (*blue line*) flowing through several violet polygons (*selected in yellow*). Both of the yellow polygons are crossed by the green one (labeled Žulová, which is a boundary of a county), but the river actually flows through the only one of them (labeled 2-04-04-044) and the other one *is only touched* by the end point of the river.

The query I have so far looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        poradi 
        ,ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(toky.geom))
        ,ST_Centroid(pov.geom)) AS dist
FROM 
        povodi_iv AS pov
        ,cr_osy_toku_snap_2m AS toky
        ,$table
WHERE 
        toky.gid = $gid // river id
    AND 
             $table.uid = $id // county id
    AND 
             ST_Intersects($table.geom, pov.geom)
    AND 
             ST_Intersects(toky.geom, pov.geom)
ORDER BY 
        dist ;
```

But it gives me the result you see on the picture.

Could anyone help me out to build a query that would **return only the violet polygons that are both crossed by county boundary and flown through by a river?**

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

Comment: I think the function you're looking for is [ST_Crosses](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Crosses.html)

Comment: I tried this with no success. `SELECT DISTINCT poradi, ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(toky.geom)),ST_Centroid(pov.geom)) AS dist
   FROM povodi_iv AS pov, cr_osy_toku_snap_2m AS toky, $table
   WHERE toky.gid = $gid
   AND $table.uid = $id
   AND ST_Intersects($table.geom, pov.geom)
   AND ST_Crosses(toky.geom, pov.geom)
   ORDER BY dist`
Any hints?

Comment: so your problem is that your query returns polygons that are **touched** by the river and not cross through them?

Comment: Exactly. I need only polygons that river goes through to be returned, not the one that are touched, but not crossed.

Comment: How sure you are the features only *touches* each other? I think that if you look *really close* you will see that they **intersect somehow**, even by a tiny fragment, and thus giving you that result.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's gonna be a real tough one, but I have to solve it somehow. Thinking of making some kind of ST_Intersection on polygons and then controlling an area of parts of each polygon splitted by the river.

Answer (score 1):

Well check for the "kind of intersection".
Translating your predicate below to human language:

```
WHERE 
        toky.gid = $gid // river id
    AND 
             $table.uid = $id // county id
    AND 
             ST_Intersects($table.geom, pov.geom)
    AND 
             ST_Intersects(toky.geom, pov.geom)
```

Want data where the river toki has the identifier - toky.gid = $gid - and also there is a county which must have code equals to - $table.uid = $id. The county geometry must have "contact" with the pov and the river must have "contact" with a county - AND ST_Intersects(toky.geom, pov.geom).

You did not requested which type of "contact" you want. You need to say that also the river must have a contact of kind "pass inside" of pov.geom.

Maybe this addition solves:

```
AND st_geometrytype( st_intersection(toky.geom, pov.geom) ) IN ( 'ST_Polygon', 'ST_MultiPolygon' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the polygons, which only touch the river, maybe it helps, if you write:

```
WHERE
     ...
  AND
     ST_Intersects(toky.geom, pov.geom) AND NOT St_touches(toky.geom, pov.geom)
```

or use ST_Relate instead of ST_Intersects